# Derivative of a distance to a surface

Tags: derivatives, surfaces

Given a surface described by an implicit equation $f(x,y,z,s)=0$ and a point $A(x_A, x_B, x_C)$.

$s$ is a shape parameter. For example, in $y=ax+b$, we have $s=(a,b)$

1-I am looking for the best method to calculate (numerically at least) the distance: $d(A,f)$.

2-I need also the expression of the derivative of the distance with respect to $s$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: NB that $d(A, f)$ need not even be defined everywhere, even if $\{f = 0\}$ is itself smooth.

Comment: In this case I suppose that it exists. The main problem for me is to calculate the first and the scond derivatives.